# If C# code is JIT compiled why do I have to choose a target platform in Visual Studio when building?

Tags: c#, jit

My assumption could be wrong, but I thought that the main advantage of JIT compilation is that allows a single distributable that the JIT compiler will compile for the target machines particular hardware.

If this is true, then why can a target platform be specified when compiling C#?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Much of the time you don't need to, and the default is okay. However, there are some circumstances where the default `Any CPU` can cause problems. One example is if you have a dependency on a 32-bit unmanaged dll. If you leave it at `Any CPU` and try to run this on a 64-bit system, the JITter will build your .Net code into a 64-bit executable, which will then fail to successfully load the 32-bit dependency. There are other cases as well where it's advantageous to be able to specify the platform. Another example is when you're building an application that you *know* will be used to load very large data sets into memory. If those data sets could exceed the virtual address space available for 32-bit programs, you may need to specify that you're building a 64-bit application.

Comment: Another reason: 32-bit programs sometimes use less memory, so in some cases that could be a factor.